# SQL: How to find string occurrences, sort them randomly by key and assign them to new attributes?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, select

I have the following sample data:

```
    key | source_string       
   ---------------------
   1355 | hb;am;dr;cc;         
   3245 | am;xa;sp;cc;       
   9831 | dr;hb;am;ei;
```

What I need to do:

1. Find strings from a fixed list ('hb','am','dr','ac') in the source_string
2. Create 3 new attributes and assign the found strings to them randomly but fixed (no difference after query re-execution)
3. If possible no subqueries and all in one SQL SELECT statement

The solution should look like this:

```
    key | source_string | t_1 | t_2 | t_3
   ---------------------------------------
   1355 | hb;am;dr;cc;  | hb  | dr  |    
   3245 | am;xa;sp;cc;  | am  |     |   
   9831 | dr;hb;am;ei;  | hb  | dr  | am
```

My thought process:

1. I wanted to return the strings that occurred per row -> 1355: hb,am,dr,cc, (no idea how)
2. Rank them based on the key to have it randomly (maybe with rank() and mod())
3. Assign the strings based on their rank to the new attributes. At key 1355 4 attributes match, but only 3 need to be assigned, so the one left has to be ignored.
   (Everything in Postgres)

In my current solution I created a rule for every case, which results in a huge query which is not desirable.

Comment: You show `'cc'` in the results, but it is not one of the strings you are looking for.

Comment: That's right, edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple method is to split the string, reaggregate the matches to an array and use that for the results

```
select t.*,
       ar[1], ar[2], ar[3]
from t cross join lateral
     (select array_agg(el order by random()) as ar
      from regexp_split_to_table(t.source_string, ';') el
      where el in ('hb','am','dr','ac')
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e5790e7ec52ddae4c43177c048e1264a) is a db<>fiddle;

Comment: This looks great, thank you! If there's a solution with less advanced functions as those I've mentioned above it would be also very helpful.

Comment: I guess, 'order by random()' does not fix their random order and seeding is not possible. I thought of using the key as a source for fixed randomness but have no idea how.

Comment: @clemens_m_b . . . I don't know what your last comment means.  If you run this multiple times (for instance in the Fiddle), you will see that it returns different values each time.

Comment: You are right. What I need is a 'fixed randomness', so after every execution, the attribute assignment should be the same: Now, after re-execution the order changes every time. I'm looking for a fixed solution, e.g. based on the key, that is always the same. For clarification: Equale string sets should be ordered differently/randomly, but have to keep their specific randomness.

Comment: @clemens_m_b . . . This answers the question you have asked here, with a fiddle to demonstrate the solution.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Comment: In my question I asked  'randomly but fixed (no difference after query re-execution)'